# Set image in listview

Tags: android

I am new in android and i am facing a problem in "ListAdapter adapter" line can any one help me below i mentioned my code in which image is not displaying because of map.put image value can't convert back to int from string.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int id;
private Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
private ImageView aImage;
private Bitmap bMap;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> values = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //aImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.AImage);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    java.lang.reflect.Field[] list = R.drawable.class.getFields();
    //for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    for (int i=0;i<9;i++){
    try {
        id = list[i].getInt(null);
        today.setToNow();

        //System.out.println("------------------"+id+"---------------");

        bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), id);

        bMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap, 50, 50, true);
        //aImage.setImageBitmap(bMap);          

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


        map.put("img", String.valueOf(bMap));

        map.put("time", today.format("%k:%M"));

        values.add(map);

        new CheckinDetail().execute();          


    } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    }       
}

class CheckinDetail extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                //int in = Integer.valueOf(et.getText().toString());

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, values,  R.layout.rowlayout, new String[] { "img","time"},new int[] { R.id.AImage, R.id.time});

                  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                  listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            }
        });

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use HashMap<String, Bitmap> map = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
In that case you can put Bitmap instances into hash set.

Answer (score 0):

Use `List<Map<String, Object>>` instead.
In that case you could put object of different types as a value.

In your case it would be:

```
// definition
private List<Map<String, Object>> values = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

// ...
// initialization

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("img", bMap);
map.put("timeString", today.format("%k:%M"));
values.add(map);
```

Then, to make this work with `SimpleAdapter` you need to give him a custom `SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder` where you shoud extract bitmap from map and set it to correspondent UI element (ImageView).